# Excel Search & compare 2 or more cell for result

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

I'm little struggle on my this project. Please see a photo I attached [image] All I want is A3 and B3 match (Drop down List) then automatically come salary on C3 if match but if not match then show 0.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()` like-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($J$3:$J$5=A3)*($K$3:$K$5=B3)*$L$3:$L$5)
```

Or `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER($L$3:$L$5,($J$3:$J$5=A3)*($K$3:$K$5=B3),0)
```

[image]